# What's a good way to parse an XML file into a C# IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dynamic

Let's say I had an xml file like this:

```
<items>
 <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Item 1</name>
    <description>This is item 1</description>
    <quantityLeft>10</quantityLeft>
  </item>
... (more items)
</items>
```

I'd like to parse it into a C# dynamic, where the tag names (name, description, etc...) become the property on the dynamic (and contains the data within the tags).

Where I could then do a query `.Where (i => i.id = 1)` for specific items in the `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, make some changes, and then update the XML file.

The XML file won't be too long, I just need it to act as a DB for a tiny app, where there will be no connectivity to an actual RDBMS.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

Comment: You can create a dynamic class using System.Reflection.Emit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***could*** load the XML file into an XDocument, copy each item to an ExpandoObject, manipulate that, copy the items back to an XDocument, and save to an XML file.

*Load*:

```
List<dynamic> items = XDocument
    .Load("input.xml")
    .Element("items")
    .Elements("item")
    .Select(item =>
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var element in item.Elements())
            dict[element.Name.LocalName] = (string)element;
        return (dynamic)dict;
    })
    .ToList();
```

*Manipulate:*

```
var query = from item in items 
            where item.id == "1"
            select item;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.name = "New Name";
}
```

*Save:*

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("items", items.Select(item =>
{
    IDictionary<string, object> dict = item as ExpandoObject;
    return new XElement("item", from kvp in dict
                                select new XElement(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
})));

doc.Save("output.xml");
```

I'm sure there are much better options though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's about what I was looking for. Honestly, this app is teen, tiny, with very little necessity for re-usability, etc.. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to update an xml file, without re-writing the entire thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx

As a sidenode: Xml to dynamic isnt very flexible. What to do with namespaces for example? Why not use XLinq? It requires a little more typing but allows you to keep beeing flexible and avoids dynamic typing which in my honest oppinion is no good candidate in conjuction with XML.